# Is it possible to specify a "no proxy" value in the AWS SDK NET S3-related libraries?

Tags: amazon-s3, proxy, aws-sdk-net

I am curious if AWSSDK.S3 has no_proxy-related settings?  For example I would like to specify that `s3.awsamazon.com` not be proxied to. In many other languages/environments I am familiar with how to do this, i.e. via an environment variable like `NO_PROXY` or a switch like `--no-proxy`, but am I correct in thinking that AWS SDK NET does not natively support this?

If the AWS SDK NET library has a broader-scoped setting for such a value then an example of how to "plug it in" to the s3 code would be much appreciated.

I have googled the matter and found [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/Util/TProxyConfig.html) and [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/v2/developer-guide/net-dg-config-ref.html); the former looks promising but can I *use* this with my AWSSDK.S3 code?  Again, if so: how?  An example would be nice; the latter does not seem to offer an actual "no proxy" setting, only a "proxy" setting.  Is there another way?  Should I be using AWSSDK.S3Control

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.